# How to avoid retyping type information for aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr, aggregate-initialization

I have the following example:

```
#include <array>

struct A {
    const char* str;
    const char* str2;
};

template<size_t N>
struct As {
    std::array<A,N> elems_;
};


template<class... Args>
As(Args...)->As<sizeof...(Args)>; //<-- NOTE: deduction guide !


constexpr static As as{A{"a","b"}, A{"1","2"}};//<-- 'retyping' A here


int main() {
  return as.elems_.size(); 
}
```

[Link to non-working example](https://godbolt.org/z/aIdgaa)

While this codes works, I would like to avoid the 'retyping' of `A`'s inside the aggregate list, but if I leave it out the deduction guide fails with: `"cannot deduce template arguments for 'As'"` (which, I guess makes sense). Maybe one way to fix this would be by hand-writing whatever number of deduction guides i need since then I could write the `A` type in each deduction guide (that is: one deduction for each size I need of the container).

Comment: Is an additional set of { } in the initialization okay?

Comment: @Columbo I guess that could be fine - anyway If theres a solution to be found using that it might help other users.

Comment: `{..}` has no type, so `Args...` cannot be deduced if `A` is omitted.

Answer (score 5):

Nested aggregate initialization has the more or less surprising behavior that you *don't* add nested `{`/`}` to match.

For example, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/yEO3_i) is how you initialize `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>`:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> arr = { 1, 1, 2, 2 };
```

Doing `{ {1, 1}, {2, 2} }` does [not](https://godbolt.org/z/RI6IQM) work!

Similarly, aggregate initialization in your case would require no nested `{`/`}` with CTAD already done (well, the template parameter given):

```
constexpr static As<2> as{"a","b", "1","2"}; // Ok!
```

Knowing that, we can just add the following deduction guide:

```
template<class ... Ts>
As(Ts...) -> As<(sizeof...(Ts) + 1)/2>;
```

This chooses `N` as "half the number of arguments". And indeed, now you can initialize like this:

```
constexpr static As as{"a","b", "1","2"}; // Deduces N = 2.
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oznEwl

*Yes, this loses the ability to structure the input with `{`/`}` for better readability, but I blame aggregate initialization here (see nested array example above).*

Comment: `(sizeof...(Ts)+1)/2`?

Comment: +1: In my actual case I cannot use this directly, since I have some more members in the `A` struct thats only specified sometimes. Even then, this answers the question as stated pretty well. Im holding this open to see if more answers show up.

Comment: @Columbo I guess it's more correct than what I wrote at first, although I'd consider checking that `sizeof...` is even. Depends on the use case (i.e. whether you really want to initialize the last member with `nullptr` if too few initializers are given) which is better.

Comment: nice answer. But I wonder what if `As` has fields of different type? For example: `struct As { const char* str; const int value;};`

Comment: @MarekR Nothing in this answer depends on the field type. The deduction guide accepts any number of different argument types. The actual initialization is all done via aggregate initialization, the deduction guide is solely for figuring out the template arguments to use.

Comment: Would requires some SFINAE though, as we expect `As<4>` for `A a{/*..*/}; As as{a, a, a, a}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 True, but then the next step is "What if you mix `As` and `const char*` pairs in the initializer?"... We can take this far down the rabbit hole. I mean, should be easily solvable with a recursive variadic helper template to peel either of these cases off one by one. The aggregate initialization side seems happy about mix-n-match though, that's a nice surprise to me: https://godbolt.org/z/5Xv2PQ

Comment: *Doing `{ {1, 1}, {2, 2} }` does not work!* That is because you haven't fully expanded it out to be what is supposed to be.  Using `{{ {1, 1}, {2, 2} }}` works since the outer brace creates the array, the inner outer brace creates the initializer list for the outer array, and the inner braces are each element.  You could also go all out and use `{{ {{1, 1}}, {{2, 2}} }};` to be pedantically specific.

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow, I didn't know that! It hadn't crossed my mind to use 3 or 4 layers of braces for a structure that is only 2 layers deep... Can you do anything useful at compile-time with this sort of initializer though? `std::initializer_list` obscures the number of elements in my understanding...

Comment: Not really anything useful.  Brace initialization is a pain because braces have no type.  You run into the same issues when you try and use CTAD with a `std::map` because of all of the nested braces.  I think they are trying to work out a fix, but I have no idea if they'll be able to pull it off.